# Returning data from modal body template in Angular modal service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using [Dan Wahlin's](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/building-an-angularjs-modal-service) modal service and got it working, however if I change *modal.html* to include a partial template in the body, I don't know how to get the model data from the template in the modal's 'ok' click result.

There are two similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034694/returning-data-from-angularjs-modal-dialog-service) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767584/how-to-pass-input-value-to-controller-in-angular-modal-service), but they have the model data inside the modal form, not in a separate template.

My thinking is that I could have a template controller for the result data, but then how would I access it from the modal service and return it to the calling controller?

modal.html:

```
<div class="inmodal">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">{{modalOptions.headerText}}</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div ng-include="modalOptions.bodyTemplateUrl" ></div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-ng-click="modalOptions.close()">{{modalOptions.closeButtonText}}</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="modalOptions.ok();">{{modalOptions.actionButtonText}}</button>
</div>
```

controller:

```
var modalOptions = {
            closeButtonText: 'Cancel',
            actionButtonText: 'Save',
            headerText: 'Modal Title',
            bodyText: 'Nicy body.',
            bodyTemplateUrl: 'modules/users/views/account/user-password.partial.html' 
        };
modalService.showModal({}, modalOptions).then(function (result) {
            console.log(result.currentPassword);
            if (result === 'ok') {
                $scope.changeUserPassword();
            }
        });
```

user-password.partial.html:

```
<div > <!-- PasswordController? -->
<form name="passwordForm" class=" form-horizontal" autocomplete="off">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" id="currentPassword" name="currentPassword" class="form-control" data-ng-model="passwordDetails.currentPassword" placeholder="Current password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" id="newPassword" name="newPassword" class="form-control" data-ng-model="passwordDetails.newPassword" placeholder="New password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" id="verifyPassword" name="verifyPassword" class="form-control" data-ng-model="passwordDetails.verifyPassword" placeholder="Verify password">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I didn't create a plunker as the links above show the same code except for the bodyTemplateUrl that I've included.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your partial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ng-include `onload` function to define a variable which will be available in the modal and the included html:

```
<div ng-include="modalOptions.bodyTemplateUrl" onload="passwordDetails = {}"></div>
```

Then send it to the `ok` method:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="modalOptions.ok(passwordDetails)">{{modalOptions.actionButtonText}}</button>
```

Check [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3dwZHO6PTbFgWlUEZU21?p=preview)

Comment: That was the missing piece! I appreciate your time and the detailed plunker.

Comment: This was very helpful. What I did, instead of using the ng-include, I built that content right into my version of modal.html.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) you will see that is says "This directive creates new scope.". So that means when you use `ng-include` *passwordDetails* is looking at a child scope of your controller. You can tell your child models to look at the parent scope by prepending your model with `$parent`.

Something like `$parent.modelName`.

Comment: Ok, I understand the _new scope_ issue now, but I'm still not sure how I'd get that child scope model data to my modal controller's 'ok' result. Do you have a code snippet to help me understand?